# WSO2 Identity Server Assertion without SessionNotOnOrAfter in AuthnStatement

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I noticed that assertion from WSO2 Identity Server have not property `SessionNotOnOrAfter` in `AuthnStatement`.

How can I force it to be added?

Comment: which version of IS are you using?

Comment: @farasath I'm using version 5.1.0

Comment: This was added in later versions. Is there a possibility for you to tryout with IS 5.3.0?

Comment: @farasath, thank you, I haven't posibility to change version. I will get expiration time from NotOnOrAfter in Conditions property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How @farasath said, this was added in later versions than 5.1.0.

For 5.1.0 workaround can be retrieving expiration time of session from `NotOnOrAfter` property in `Conditions` tag in assertion.